# LaTeX-workshop: badge does not appear

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I've installed latex-workshop on VSCode for Mac, and watching videos on YouTube there should be a "TeX" badge (?) on the left side of the screen, right under the Extensions badge. There isn't. What step did I miss?

extension: https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop

Comment: Could you please link to the extension?

Comment: What exactly did you install on VSCode? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=latex&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance None of them is called latex-studio. Find an up-to-date video guide please, as the whole ecosystem changed in the past.

Comment: sorry: latex-workshop

Answer (score 6):

Turns out that the badge appears once you open a TeX file. I thought you'd first create a TeX project, then the file.

Answer (score 0):

As you already figured out, the badge appears once you open a TeX file. Keep also in mind that you have to install LaTeX, or update LaTex. I say so because personally I was trying to use `\tableofcontents` but the table wouldn't be generated until the moment I installed texlive using homebrew (`brew install texlive`)